# Is it possible to use a font not included in QGIS for layer styles and layout maps?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, style, font

Is it possible to use a font not included in QGIS for layer styles and layout maps? If so, how?

I am using QGIS 3.18.2 at the moment.

Sorry I don't know where to start here as I have not been able to find any information on this process online.

I have downloaded a .zip archive with a series of .tff files and am wondering if QGIS can access those files (or other font file formats) and use them in layer styles/layout maps?

Comment: Have you installed those .ttf fonts on your computer?

Comment: No. Ha! Doing so is the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think QGIS uses system fonts. If the fonts are installed in the system, you can use them in QGIS. Install the fonts individually and see if they appear in the QGIS fonts dropdown.

Comment: Thank you!! That is the solution. Easily done on Win 10 by right clicking the .tff file > Open With > Windows Font Viewer > Install (top left button) > Reload QGIS.